# Как выбрать отсутствующие записи из одной таблицы в отношении many-to-many?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

Описываю отношения many-to-many тремя таблицами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить бейджи пользователя John мне предельно ясно. Я делаю это вот таким запросом:

```
select b.* from Badges b
join Userbages ub on (b.bid = ub.bid)
join Users u on (ub.uid = u.uid) where u.uid = 1
```

Но я совсем не могу понять как мне получить те бейджи, которых у Джона нет. То есть сделать exclusion имеющихся записей в выборке из одной таблицы, на основании id из другой. И именно в отношениях many-to-many. То есть для пользователя John мне нужно выбрать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои четырёхчасовые исследования ничего не прояснили. Я находил конструкции с `left outer join` и `where (u.uid is null)`, но, похоже, в many-to-many так не работает.

У меня нет сомнений, что это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если искать по таблице **Badges**, тогда получаем *все возможные* бэйджи, которых нет у джона:

```
select b.* from public.badges b
where b.bid not in (select ub.bid from public.users u
  left join public.userbadges ub on u.uid = ub.uid
  where u.customer = 'John')
```

Если искать по таблице **UserBadges**, тогда получаем *все используемые* бэйджи, которых нет у джона:

```
select distinct b.* from public.userbadges ub
  left join public.badges b on ub.bid = b.bid
where ub.bid not in (select ub.bid from public.users u
  left join public.userbadges ub on u.uid = ub.uid
  where u.customer = 'John')
```

---

PostgreSQL